# Checking whether a text box contain only digits

Tags: c#, validation, textbox

I am done with this problem(using an alternative method). But still don't know why the following method is not working. Please help

Aim: when leave from a text box 
     check whether it contain only digits-then allow to leave.
     If not show an error provider.
     check whether string length is **not more than 7 and not 0** -then allow to leave.
     if not show an error provider.

Code that doesn't seem working is given below! :

```
private void textBox24_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
bool result = true;

        foreach (char y in textBox24.Text)
        {
            while (y < '0' || y > '9')
                result = false;
        }

        if (result == false)
        {
            errorProvider4.SetError(textBox24, "Enter digits only");
            textBox24.Focus();
        }
        else if (textBox24.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            errorProvider4.SetError(textBox24, "Enter the value");
            textBox24.Focus();
        }
        else if (textBox24.Text.Length > 7)
        {
            errorProvider4.SetError(textBox24, "Maximum length is 7 digits");
            textBox24.Focus();
        }
        else
            errorProvider4.Clear();
}
```

problem with this code:

when I enter input other than digits, it gets stuck.
May be this wont be a big question. However help me.

code that now I am using:

```
private void textBox24_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
int check = 123;
        bool result = int.TryParse(textBox24.Text, out check);
        if (result == false)
        {
            errorProvider4.SetError(textBox24, "Only digits are allowed");
            textBox24.Focus();
        }
        else if (textBox24.Text.Length > 7)
        {
            errorProvider4.SetError(textBox6, "Invalid value");
            textBox24.Focus();
        }
        else
            errorProvider4.Clear();
}
```

Comment: if user enter value like `0001.0' validation will pass, is that what you expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside while loop you have condition if true you set the result as true but loop running forever because condition again true.

```
foreach (char y in textBox24.Text)
{
  while (condition) // this is run forever if true
      result = false;

}
```

you can use `break;` if true case like below

```
foreach (char y in textBox24.Text)
{
  while (condition){ 
      result = false;
      break;
   }

}
```

**Few more Suggestion..**

1. TextBox control having property called `MaxLength` you can set it as 7 to limit user input up to 7 characters
2. if you need to allow only digits don't use `int.TryParse` method. if input with decimal points will pass the validation.
3. to check string contains only digits you can use code like `if (textBox1.Text.ToCharArray().Any(c=>!Char.IsDigit(c)))`
4. if validation fail you need to set `e.Cancel = true;`

Comment: The `break` only breaks out of the `while`, not out of the `foreach`. Change the `while` to an `if` for the intended result.